# Prevent table from spliting if it fits on one page (GS PDFFlow)

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, .net-6.0

I am generating a PDF using the GS PDFFlow library (Gehtsoft.PDFFlowLib) in C# with .net 6. Currently, I am using only one type of table, but the number of rows generated varies depending on the content. The problem is that the layout doesn't look good when there is some space left on a page, and my next table gets split across two pages. For instance, sometimes I end up with two rows on page 1 and one row on page 2, which is not the desired outcome. Ideally, I would like the table to remain on one page if it fits entirely.

Unfortunately, the GS PDFFlow documentation does not provide any guidance on how to achieve this. While I know I can use a function to insert a page break, I don't want to do that after every table. Additionally, I have attempted to find a suitable function to determine the remaining space on a page, but haven't had any luck.
I also tried to use SetKeepWithNext(), but this function is just messing up the table.

Do you have any ideas on how I could resolve this issue?